# sqlite3.OperationalError: ambiguous column name: views

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-update

Help! I try to update the select statement but it seems to not work here
So, let me introduced my table `Artists` and `Songs`

**Note**:I already inserted these table yet

```
c.execute("""create table Artists(
        Artist_id INTEGER primary key,
        artist char(255),
        Most_listened_song char(255));""")



c.execute("""create table Songs(
        Song_ID INTEGER Primary key,
        Song char(255),
        Artist_ID INTEGER,
        FtArtist_ID INTEGER null,
        Genre_ID INTEGER,
        dates Date,
        views INTEGER,
        Foreign key(Artist_ID) references Artists(Artist_ID),
        Foreign key(FtArtist_ID) references Artists(Artist_ID),Foreign Key(Genre_ID) references Genres(Genre_ID));""")
```

and, this is where I update SELECT statement and cause me an error

```
    result1='Roar'
    result2='Katy Perry'

    c.execute("""UPDATE Songs Set views = views+1 FROM Songs 
                 Inner join Artists On Artists.Artist_ID = Songs.Artist_ID
                 where Song = ? and Artist = ?""",(result1,result2,))
```

This is the error

```
 sqlite3.OperationalError: ambiguous column name: views
```

So I decided to change from `views` to  `Songs.views`

```
result1='Roar'
result2='Katy Perry'

c.execute("""UPDATE Songs Set Songs.views = Songs.views+1 FROM Songs 
             Inner join Artists On Artists.Artist_ID = Songs.Artist_ID
             where Song = ? and Artist = ?""",(result1,result2,))
```

and, it still gave me the error after running

`sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".": syntax error`

Which one should I edit

Comment: Side note: The column `Most_listened_song` in `Artists`. That's information that can be calculated from the data in `Songs` and therefore shouldn't be materialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of SQLite is 3.33.0+ then you can use SQlite's [`UPDATE-FROM`](https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html#update_from) extension to `UPDATE` statement, with this syntax:

```
UPDATE Songs 
SET views = views + 1 
FROM Artists 
WHERE Artists.Artist_ID = Songs.Artist_ID 
AND Songs.Song = ? AND Artists.Artist = ?
```

For previous versions of SQLite you can do it with a subquery:

```
UPDATE Songs 
SET views = views + 1
WHERE Song = ? 
AND Artist_ID = (SELECT Artist_ID FROM Artists WHERE Artist = ?)
```